# What's the point of drinking light booze?

Tags: taste, alcohol-level

I hear alcohol itself has no delicious flavor, if any, also light drinks have such a small amount of alcohol that won't make you feel tipsy. So it's a question for me why is there alcohol in light drinks and why people take the risk of toxifying themselves by drinking it when it has no good effects? Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The effects of alcohol are well known. It makes you relax, uninhibited and generally have a good time up to a point. I once had a couple of friends that would order their Coors Light beer on crushed ice. It was awful, but they did it anyway as a way to slow down the consumption. I think that's generally what people are doing when there is less alcohol in a drink. They like to get buzzed and don't want to be drunk. Personally, I like to drink a fair amount of beer so if I know I am going to have more than a couple of beers, I will choose a lower alcohol beer (not necessarily a lite beer) instead of an IPA. I also drink cider instead of wine for the same purpose.

So, I think people like to drink something but not get drunk.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what farmersteve said: Pure alcohol doesn't have a taste, but lower-alcohol beers, wines, ciders, meads, etc do.  Sometimes what you're looking for is the taste, not the alcohol -- the grain (or grapes etc), not the alcohol itself.  So I challenge the claim that there is *no* benefit.

Comment: Plus they can hydrate you if the alcohol is low enough